# WebMatrix how can you enable the POST method

Tags: forms, post, webmatrix

I have a form action that I am trying to use, but, when I submit the form, I get the HTTP Error 405.0 - Method Not Allowed.

```
<form action="" method="post">
```

I am using WebMatrix on my local machine.  I have been told that I need to enable the POST method within WebMatrix through a configuration file or something, but can't find anything that tells me how to do that.

Answer (score 1):

If you're having ASP.NET Running on WebMatrix, then you must have IIS server in your computer too. So, for that you need to be looking for methods and codes to make the web.config work with IIS.

On the following page it has been told how you can allow or deny types of Requests.

http://www.petefreitag.com/item/741.cfm

`security` --> `requestFiltering` -->

```
<verbs allowUnlisted="false" applyToWebDAV="true">
    <add verb="GET" allowed="true" />
    <add verb="POST" allowed="true" />
</verbs>
```

Furthermore, you can see that IIS is disabled to accept HttpGet and HttpPost requests by Default. http://support.microsoft.com/kb/819267/en-us Go to the link and learn how to enable them.

I hope it allows that.

Secondly, also try using `POST` instead of `post`. Maybe that would be an issue in IIS. Do try this second method.